# What commands are available to visualize the data pages on SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

From [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280360.aspx):

> *The page is the fundamental unit of
>   data storage in SQL Server. An extent
>   is a collection of eight physically
>   contiguous pages. Extents help
>   efficiently manage pages.*
>
> *This section describes the data
>   structures that are used to manage
>   pages and extents. Understanding the
>   architecture of pages and extents is
>   important for designing and developing
>   databases that perform efficiently.*

So what commands/utilities are available to visualize the data pages on SQL Server ?

Comment: As you also requested utilities you might want to check out the management studio addin. SQL Server Internals Viewer on Codeplex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DBCC PAGE](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=DBCC%20PAGE)

Paul Randal also has lots of stuff about [on-disk structures](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/category/On-Disk-Structures.aspx) and articles ["Anatomy of a (insert storage thing here)"](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/search.aspx?q=anatomy) (some overlap here of course)